Can we chant the Saraswati kavacham without initiation?
As an uninitiated upasaka , we are forbidden to chant the the Beeja mantras. But kavacham like bhairava kavacha and Saraswati kavacha have Beeja mantras in it. I am very interested to chant the Saraswati kavacham but due to the presence of Beeja mantras I am very much in tussle whether to do it or not. Please can I have any scriptural and personal suggestions ?

Strictly (according to scriptures) such recital might be fruitless but IMO you can recite and then ask for forgiveness from the deity who rules that Stotra.
